# Use PostGIS geometry types in SQLModel

Tags: python, postgis, sqlmodel, geoalchemy2

Is it possible to use PostGIS geometry types in models created in SQLModel? If yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is.

Just take advantage of the `sqlalchemy` package that makes the work underneath `SQLModel` and the the `GeoAlchemy2` package which is compatible with `sqlalchemy` and has already defined geometry types.

So,

```
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Column

class Record(SQLModel, table=True):
    point: Any = Field(sa_column=Column(Geometry('POINT'))) # Here POINT is used but could be other geometries as well
```